# How to combine `stat` and `md5sum` output line by line?

Tags: linux, bash, exec, stat, md5sum

stat part:

```
$ find * -depth -exec stat --format '%n %U %G' {} + | sort -d > acl_file
$ cat acl_file
xfce4/desktop/icons screen0-3824x1033.rc john john
Code/CachedData/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/index-ec362010a4d520491a88088c200c853d.code john john
VirtualBox/selectorwindow.log.6 john john
```

- md5sum part:

$ find * -depth -exec md5sum {} + | sort -d > md5_file
$ cat md5_file

```
3da180c2d9d1104a17db0749d527aa4b  xfce4/desktop/icons screen0-3824x1033.rc
3de44d64a6ce81c63f9072c0517ed3b9  Code/CachedData/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/index-ec362010a4d520491a88088c200c853d.code
3f85bb5b59bcd13b4fc63d5947e51294  VirtualBox/selectorwindow.log.6
```

How to combine `stat --format '%n %U %G'` and `md5sum` and output to file line by line,such as:

```
3da180c2d9d1104a17db0749d527aa4b  xfce4/desktop/icons screen0-3824x1033.rc john john
3de44d64a6ce81c63f9072c0517ed3b9  Code/CachedData/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/index-ec362010a4d520491a88088c200c853d.code john john
3f85bb5b59bcd13b4fc63d5947e51294  VirtualBox/selectorwindow.log.6 john john
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really just a minor variation on @Zilog80's solution. My time testing had it a few seconds faster by skipping `read`s on a smallish dataset of a few hundred files running on a windows laptop under git bash. YMMV.

```
mapfile -t lst< <( find . -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; -exec stat --format '%U %G' "{}"  \; )
for ((i=0; i < ${#lst[@]}; i++)); do if (( i%2 )); then echo "${lst[i]}"; else printf "%s " "${lst[i]}"; fi done | sort -d
```

---

## edit

My original solution was pretty broken.  It was skipping files in hidden subdirectories, and the `printf` botched filenames with spaces. If you don't have hidden directories to deal with, or if you *want* to skip those (e.g., you're working in a `git` repo and would rather skip the `.git` tree...), here's a rework.

---

```
shopt -s dotglob    # check hidden files 
shopt -s globstar   # process at arbitrary depth
for f in **/*; do   # this properly handles odd names
  [[ -f "$f" ]] && echo "$(md5sum "$f") $(stat --format "%U %G" "$f")"
done | sort -d
```

Comment: If you literally want just *files*, use `[[ -f "$f" ]] &&` instead of `[[ -d "$f" ]] ||`, which only eliminates directories.

Comment: As `md5sum` is careless about directory,then I use `--depth` to show files first.If `for` goes to `directory`,how to set md5sum as null?

Comment: This solution  will skip directories, but is going to miss files in hidden subdirectories that `find -type f` will list. Looking into a solution for that.

Comment: Is `-type f` sufficient? Doesn't `--depth` still give the errors, just later?

Comment: @PaulHodges Nice improvement with `mapfile`. And good idea to use globing instead of `find` in the edit, that one will limit memory usage.

Comment: Unless you need a file in a hidden directory, lol

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way should be :

```sh
find * -type f -exec stat --format '%n %U %G' "{}"  \; -exec md5sum "{}" \; |
{ while read -r line1 && read -r line2; do printf "%s %s\n" "${line2/ */}" "${line1}";done; } | 
sort -d
```

We use two `-exec` to apply `stat` and `md5sum` file by file, then we read both output lines and use `printf` to format one output line by file with both the output of `stat`/ `md5sum`. We finally pipe the whole output to `sort`.

**Warning:**  As we pipe the whole output to sort, you may to wait that all the stat/md5sum had been done before getting any output on a console.
And if only `md5sum` and not  `stat` fails on a file (or vice versa), the output will be trashed.

**Edit:**  A way a little safer for the output :

```sh
find * -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; -exec stat --format '%n %U %G' "{}"  \;  | 
{ while read -r line; do 
   mdsum="${line/[0-9a-f]*  /}"; 
   [ "${mdsum}" != "${line}" ] && 
      { mdsumdisp="${line%  ${mdsum}}"; mdsumfile="${mdsum}"; } || 
          { [ "${line#${mdsumfile}}" != "${line}" ] &&
             printf "%s %s\n" "${mdsumdisp}" "${line}"; }; 
   done; } |  sort -d
```

Here, at least, we check we have something like a md5sum on the expected line matching the file in the line.

Comment: `sort -d` means sort by `md5` value or by `stat %n` ?

Comment: Here, as the md5 will be the first part of the line, by the alphanumeric (a-z)  characters from the md5 then the ones from `stat`.

Comment: c.f. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs - you will probably want  something more like `find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do` to handle embedded spaces, newlines, and other weirdness (we already know there are spaces).

Comment: @PaulHodges Piping through a loop and then make the `stat` and `md5sum` calls in the loop would defeat the use of a direct `-exec` regarding speed / performance. The answer is a way to achieve that keeping `-exec <operation> {}`.

Comment: And `read`ing the whole line makes it a single string which you are parsing intelligently. Should work fine for spaces in this case.

Comment: @PaulHodges I agree anyway that it's not very reliable (too many potential points of failure). Should be ok for _one shot_, but for _operations_ it would be better to use/make a `stat` process able to also output a md5sum.